# Can you parallelize panel maneuvers in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, multidplyr

**In my R script**, I'm using the pmdplyr functions `mutate_cascade()` and `tlag()` to mutate my data, which contains over 3 million records, so the code is extremely slow but it works. In order to speed things up, I tried adding the parallel processing functions of multidplyr. But it's throwing up *Error: All columns in a tibble must be vectors. x Column `.` is a `multidplyr_party_df` object.*  Is that because it's not possible to run the pmdplyr pibble on a multidplyr cluster? I'm new to both pmdplyr and multidplyr, so maybe I'm just doing something wrong?

I get a consolidated `import_data` dataset with variables `uuid, location_id, import_date, customer_name, total_value`. Anomaly imports can result in huge spikes in `total_value` so my code seeks to even out the wildly impossible swings of this value (which is relative to each customer):

````
cluster_library(cluster, "dplyr")
cluster_library(cluster, "pmdplyr")

mydata <- import_data %>%

  mutate(
    time_var = time_variable(import_date),
    id_var = id_variable(uuid, location_id),
    total_value_imported = total_value
  ) %>%

  arrange(uuid, location_id, import_date) %>%

  group_by(uuid, location_id) %>%

  partition(cluster) %>%

  pibble(
    .i = id_var,
    .t = time_var,
    .d = 0
  ) %>%

  mutate_cascade(
    total_value = case_when(
      total_value > (tlag(total_value, .n = 1, .quick = TRUE) * 10)  
        ~ tlag(total_value, .n = 1, .quick = TRUE),
      total_value < (tlag(total_value, .n = 1, .quick = TRUE) / 10) 
        ~ tlag(total_value, .n = 1, .quick = TRUE),
      TRUE ~ total_value_imported
    )
  ) %>%

  collect()

> rlang::last_error()
<error/tibble_error_column_scalar_type>
All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `.` is a `multidplyr_party_df` object.
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::mutate(...)
  1. dplyr::arrange(., uuid, location_id, import_date)
  1. dplyr::group_by(., uuid, location_id)
  1. multidplyr::partition(., cluster)
  8. pmdplyr::pibble(., .i = id_var, .t = time_var, .d = 0)
  9. tibble::tibble(...)
 10. tibble:::tibble_quos(xs[!is_null], .rows, .name_repair)
 11. tibble:::check_valid_col(res, col_names[[j]], j)
 12. tibble:::check_valid_cols(set_names(list(x), name))
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/tibble_error_column_scalar_type>
All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
x Column `.` is a `multidplyr_party_df` object.
Backtrace:
     █
  1. └─`%>%`(...)
  2.   ├─base::withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
  3.   └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  4.     └─base::eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
  5.       └─`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
  6.         └─magrittr::freduce(value, `_function_list`)
  7.           └─function_list[[i]](value)
  8.             └─pmdplyr::pibble(., .i = id_var, .t = time_var, .d = 0)
  9.               └─tibble::tibble(...)
 10.                 └─tibble:::tibble_quos(xs[!is_null], .rows, .name_repair)
 11.                   └─tibble:::check_valid_col(res, col_names[[j]], j)
 12.                     └─tibble:::check_valid_cols(set_names(list(x), name))```
````